# 405 Error, Method not allowed Django Rest Framework and ATrigger

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a webhook that get triggered by [ATrigger](http://atrigger.com/docs/). I tried it but every time it shows error 405, method not allowed.

It works when doing a POST through the server, or through [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/)

Answer (score 0):

[ATrigger](http://atrigger.com) doesn't use POST, it uses GET